# Separate numeric and string value in one line using matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have problem to read and separate some values (numeric and string) from a file to different column in Matlab like below :

```
1.000000 - 1.000200 0 -> 2 A-MPDU 1.000000 - 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 - 1.000200 FAIL
```

I want to separate each column to different arrays so later I can have : Column 1 has 1.000000 ... Column 15 has FAIL. So far I use this codes but doesn't work.

```
filename1 = 'trace';
A1 = importdata(filename1);

B1 = A1';
C1 = B1(1,:);
```

From those codes, my expectation is C1 should be 1.000000. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k] = textread(filename1, '%f - %f %d -> %d %s %f - %f %s %f - %f %s')
```

Comment: it works well. But my floating value result from 1.000000 becomes 1 only. How to make it show original value? I use %.6f but the result is the same